# What was Mad Sweeney screaming in Gaelic?

Tags: tv, languages, american-gods

In the "Prayer for Mad Sweeney" episode, the car accident throws Laura through the window and rips the golden coin from her body.

Mad Sweeney picks it up and he is ready to walk away from the dead Laura's body, but then he changes his mind - he screams something in Gaelic (I believe that at least...) to the surrounding forest, and after placing a few missing bits back into Laura's chest, he gives her back his special coin.

[image]
[image]

What was he saying?

Bonus question: What fell off from Laura's body?

Comment: I'm Canadian and don't speak a clean word of Irish. My cousin in Dublin teaches it and I could fire it off to her if there's some discrepancy in the above translations. I'll check back.
The translations so far seem to match, and the situation in the story seems to warrant it. "Man of the mounds" is "Banshee".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

VERY literally: 'What-is-it from-which this shit has befallen to me? Is it not a sufficiency I have suffered/endured? It's a sufficiency besides. I'm not evil! I'm not!'

Comment: Are you a native speaker? What is your source for this translation?

Comment: It's in medieval Irish. I teach the language at university level.

Comment: Ah. It's just that we usually require answers to be sourced, but I guess it's hard to support with sources in this case. Nevertheless, thanks for sharing this! :)

Comment: No problem: I was flabbergasted when i heard it!

Comment: Medieval irish has a word for "*a sufficiency*"? Instead of, for example, "*enough*"...

Comment: The word is lór, 'enough, sufficient', an adjective often used (as here) as a noun 'enough, a sufficiency'---there's no really distinction of meaning, I was just being very literal. In more colloquial English: 'Why does this shit happen to me? Haven't I suffered enough? It's enough besides. I'm not evil. I'm not.'

Comment: What I want to know is which of my colleagues translated this...it's grammatically perfect medieval Irish, and there are probably only about 100 people in the world who could have done it.

Comment: Personally, I think your more colloquial translation in the comments would make a very fine addition to the answer, which as it stands is sorely missing a natural translation. +1 anyway

Comment: The answer to User84740's question, "Who translated this?" is Tadhg Morris, a PhD candidate at the Centre for Medieval Studies in Toronto, who, though competent in Middle Irish, actually specializes in Classical Gaelic bardic verse.

Answer (score 15):

[This site](http://oohlo.com/2017/06/12/how-ive-waited-for-this-moment-to-be-by-your-side-american-gods-a-prayer-for-mad-sweeney/) sources fluent Gaelic speakers as translating the speech more-or-less as:

> "“Haven’t I believed enough in your bullshit? Haven’t I suffered enough? Isn’t that enough itself? I’m not evil! I’m not!”

(or, in the original tongue)

> ""Créd as co tarlaid an cac-sa-dam? Nach lór rofhulangas? Is lór chena, níam olc! Níam!"

Comment: Thanks! I will accept it, unless there will be other, contradicting translations.